# Expanding contractions in the English language using Python

Tags: python, dictionary, twitter, preprocessor

I'm trying to substitute all contractions in a tweet by defining a dictionary with the substitutions that should be used, but can't understand why this is not working:

```
tweet = "I luv <3 my iphone & you’re awsm apple. DisplayIsAwesome, sooo happppppy  http://www.apple.com"

APPOSTOPHES = {"'s": " is", "'re":" are"}  

sentence_list = tweet.split()

print(sentence_list)

new_sentence = []

for word in sentence_list:
    for candidate_replacement in APPOSTOPHES:
        if candidate_replacement in word:
            word = word.replace(candidate_replacement, APPOSTOPHES[candidate_replacement])

    new_sentence.append(word)

rfrm = " ".join(new_sentence)
print(rfrm)
```

I've tried to change the dictionary with one comprising of most common contractions, and it did not work.

The sentence which is output at the end is exactly the same as the one that was input.

Note: Before this, the tweet goes through html parsing, but I doubt that would affect anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple. You are using wrong symbol in dict APPOSTOPHES.

```
"’re" != "'re"
```

Try it with:

```
APPOSTOPHES = {"’s": " is", "’re": " are"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your input string `tweet` contains non-printable character `’` instead of single quote `'`. 
In most simple case you may extend your `APPOSTOPHES` dictionary to the following:

```
...
APPOSTOPHES = {"'s": " is", "’s": " is", "'re":" are", "’re":" are"}
```

Then, you'll get the expected result:

```
I luv <3 my iphone & you are awsm apple. DisplayIsAwesome, sooo happppppy  http://www.apple.com
```